# Does mono support IPv6 sockets?

Tags: mono

I am selecting a language to write a cross-platform networking library that my project needs. But a simple test shows mono may not support ipv6 socket.

```
Socket s;
try
{
    s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

The above code runs fine in Windows under .net. But throws an exception when using mono VM. Does anyone know if mono supports ipv6 sockets?

Comment: What exception? Runs fine here: http://ideone.com/VV8Dcx

Comment: IP v6 is supported. We can only imagine that IP v6 is disabled at OS level in your case, as you provide no other information at all.

Comment: ken2k: the exception is "An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used." Lex Li: I was testing under Windows 7. If I run the executable as is it is fine but it throws an exception if I use mono to run it.